# How to enable thumbnail selection for external links? (or: reproduce Facebook's "post to profile" functionality)

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, user-interface, screen-scraping

When posting a link to your facebook profile, users are presented with the option to choose a thumbnail to represent the link, as seen in the following example:

http://www.everyday.com.my/photo/2009/4/Add-Sushi-King-into-my-Facebook-profile.jpg (New users aren't allowed to embed images)

The thumbnails presented to the user are the different images contained on the page being shared / linked to.

Anyone have any ideas regarding what process Facebook is using to offer this feature? Specifically I would like to reproduce it using a combination of PHP/JQuery, and was hoping there might be an implementation out there already for me to build on.

Thanks!

Comment: Just to Clarify - Facebook does not use screenshots of webpages, but rather provides an interface to select single images embedded within the web page being linked to.

Answer (score 0):

Try this: http://www.thumbshots.org/

If that doesn't work out then maybe you can embed Alexa's site thumbnails.

Answer (score 0):

Another option is [websnapr.com](http://www.websnapr.com/)

You could just add something like this to your code:

```
var myurl = 'http://www.google.com';
var thumbnail = '<img src="http://images.websnapr.com/?url=' + myurl + '" alt="' + myurl + '">';

document.write(thumbnail);
```

Comment: Just to Clarify - Facebook does not take a "screenshot" of the page, like ThumbShots. Instead, it allows for the selection of specific images which are contained within the page. Hence, I would think the process Facebook users is something along the lines of:

1) Lookup page in background
2) Crawl DOM object, pick out large images
3) Create thumbnails of image
4) Display thumbnails to user

What I'm looking for is confirmation of my assumption, and even better an open-source example of this feature implemented.